# function returns immutable references but borrow checker thinks otherwise

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Here, I pass some mutable references into a function to perform some action on those. Then, I drop those mutable references by turning them into immutable references. However, the Rust borrow checker still seems to think they are mutable. Here's the code:

```rust
//! src/lib.rs
fn append_1_to_all(strings: Vec<&mut String>) -> Vec<&mut String> {
    strings.into_iter().map(|s| { s.push_str("1"); s }).collect()
}

fn get_shared_references(strings: Vec<&mut String>) -> Vec<&String> {
    strings.into_iter().map(|c| &(*c)).collect()
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let strings = vec!["one".to_string(), "two".to_string(), "three".to_string()];
    let strings_appended = append_1_to_all(strings.iter_mut().collect());

    let strings_shared = get_shared_references(strings_appended);

    assert_ne!(strings[0], *strings_shared[0]);
}
```

Compile error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `strings` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:16:16
   |
12 |     let strings_appended = append_1_to_all(strings.iter_mut().collect());
   |                                            ------- mutable borrow occurs here
...
16 |     assert_ne!(strings[0], *strings_shared[0]);
   |                ^^^^^^^      -------------- mutable borrow later used here
   |                |
   |                immutable borrow occurs here
```

How can I fix this error? I would think `strings_shared` shouldn't be related to the mutable borrow anymore.

Comment: I'm still just a beginner myself, but I wonder if `strings_shared` holds immutable references to the mutable references?

Comment: @lxop, I checked that already, but you can see in the signature that get_shared_references() only returns the Vec<&String>, not Vec<&&mut String>, so it's just the immutable reference.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is not that your reference is actually mutable, but that it's keeping the mutable reference alive.

If you have a reference, type `&'a ...` or `&'a mut ...`, and you produce another reference using it, whether that is a reborrow `&*some_reference` or a field access `&some_struct_reference.some_field` or a method or anything else, then that is *always* considered to be a *borrow* from that original reference, requiring the original reference to live as long as the derived one.

Notice that in your function declaration,

```rust
fn get_shared_references(strings: Vec<&mut String>) -> Vec<&String> {...}
```

if we change it to write out the elided lifetimes, we get this:

```rust
fn get_shared_references<'a>(strings: Vec<&'a mut String>) -> Vec<&'a String> {...}
```

In order to make this work, we'd have to be writing some other lifetime for the result, `&'b String` instead of `&'a String. **But what would that lifetime be, and how is it constrained?** It's got to last no longer than the *value it refers to* does, but be longer than the mutable reference. Rust's lifetime system doesn't have a way to express that. A near miss is:

```rust
fn get_shared_references<'m, 'i: 'm>(strings: Vec<&'m mut String>) -> Vec<&'i String> {...}
```

But even if you could implement a function with this type, it wouldn't be useful to the caller, because they don't know anything about the lifetime `'i` other than "at least as long as `'m`".

We could imagine a system where mutable references carry two lifetimes — let's suppose the syntax `&'m mut 'i T`, where `'m` is the lifetime for which the reference is mutable, and `'i` is (no longer than) the lifetime of the value. In that case, we could possibly have

```rust
fn consumes_mut_ref_produces_ref<'m, 'i>(x: &'m mut 'i i32) -> &'i i32 {...}
```

But a whole new set of lifetime rules would have to be designed to make this work, and it might not even be possible to do consistently. It's certainly not something today's Rust supports.

---

My recommendation, in the absence of further details on what you're trying to do, would be to make this code to work on **owned** values. Owned values can be passed around in the way you're trying to do — because taking them as function arguments *transfers* ownership, so there's no lifetimes to worry about, and it's much more possible to say: "my function consumes this and produces that," with no obligatory relationship.

```rust
fn append_1_to_all(mut strings: Vec<String>) -> Vec<String> {
    for s in strings.iter_mut() {
        s.push_str("1")
    }
    strings
}

fn get_shared_references(strings: &Vec<String>) -> Vec<&String> {
    // Or even better, just use strings.iter() instead of this function
    strings.iter().collect()
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let strings = vec!["one".to_string(), "two".to_string(), "three".to_string()];

    // .clone() here is necessarily only because strings is used in the assert below
    let strings_appended = append_1_to_all(strings.clone());

    let strings_shared = get_shared_references(&strings_appended);

    assert_ne!(strings[0], *strings_shared[0]);
}
```